# Alternative to break?

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to c++, and I was told not to use a 'break' statement. I was curious what are some alternatives to a 'break'? (using the example of the code below)

```
    void remove_comments( ifstream& fileIn , ofstream& fileOut)
{
  string line;
  bool flag = false;
  bool found = false;

  while (! fileIn.eof() )
  {

    getline(fileIn, line);

    if (line.find("/*") < line.length() )
      flag = true;
    if (! flag)
    {
      for (int i=0; i < line.length(); i++)
      {

        if(i<line.length())
          if ((line.at(i) == '/') && (line.at(i + 1) == '/'))
            break;
          else
            fileOut << line[i];
         }
      fileOut<<endl;


  }
  if(flag)
  {
    if(line.find("*/") < line.length() )
      flag = false;
  }

}
}
```

Comment: Who told you not to use `break`? It's the natural way to end a loop prematurely.

Comment: BTW, `while (!fileIn.eof())` is bad practice. You have to check for `eof()` _after_ performing an input operation, not before.

Comment: Related to what @Barmar alread said: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125)

Comment: There is ultimate keyword named `goto`, but definitely I prefer `break` to `goto`.

Comment: -1 for poor indentation. I cannot tell what is inside the loop. Please use a real text editor.

Comment: Seems like the easiest way to get rid of that `break` would be to use `line.find("//")` instead of the inner loop.

Comment: Depending on what your assignment requires, don't forget that the character sequences "/*" and "//" can occur inside of strings or multi-character literals and would not be considered significant as the start of a comment in that case.

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite the loop

```
for (int i=0;
     i < line.length() &&
     !(i+1 < line.length() && (line.at(i) == '/') && (line.at(i + 1) == '/'));
     ++i)
{
    fileOut << line[i];
}
fileOut<<endl;
```

Comment: De Morgan's law might help clarify the second part of the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking is sometimes necessary -- without breaks you might crash into the stuff ahead and hurt yourself.

You may also hurt yourself by thinking poorly and then solving the problem in a cryptic manner that even you won't understand 6 months later.

Lastly -- whoever told you not to use a "break" .. give him a break -- never stop by him/her/it for advise.

BTW -- work on your indentation and curlies -- not good.

Answer (score 0):

You could - and should - rewrite that loop. Mankarse showed one option, but that's got all those weird and difficult to understand conditions in the `for` loops.

You should learn to leverage the power of the standard library. For example, this code will remove all the characters that follow a C++ style line comment from the string stored in `line`:

```
// Find the first instance of two forward slashes in the line
// and return an iterator to that.
auto begin_comment = line.find("//");

// We found it! Remove all characters from that point on
if (begin_comment != std::string::npos)
    line.erase (begin_comment, line.end());

fileOut << line << std::endl;
```

Consider how you could also take small chunks of code like that and put them into functions, which you will call to do work on your behalf. This will not only keep the code more readable, but it will get you into the habit of designing interfaces, which is a very important skill to have.

---

As a sidenote, your indentation is really bad and you must work on it. Look at this gem:

```
  for (int i=0; i < line.length(); i++)
  {

    if(i<line.length())
      if ((line.at(i) == '/') && (line.at(i + 1) == '/'))
        break;
      else
        fileOut << line[i];
     }
```

Which of those two `if` statements does the `else` match up against? Are you **immediately** and **completely sure** that you are right?

To be sure, the compiler doesn't need indentation and couldn't care less for it. But you do, and you will soon find out that as your code grows more complex, unless it's properly indented, it will be impossible to understand.